# Is there a way to make Spring boot filters act asynchronously?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, servlet-filters, completable-future

I know that methods in a **Controller** in Springboot can be made asynchronous with the help of `@Async` annotation over them and `CompletableFuture<T>` as their return type, but can something similar be achieved in a Spring **filter**?

In filters, we need to implement the `doFilter` method, which returns a void. Is there any way it could be made asynchronous?

Link to any resource is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. 
Spring Security's filters are an implementation of the **chain of responsibility** pattern.

https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture / **Web Security**

> At most one servlet can handle a single request, but filters form a
>   chain, so they are ordered, and in fact a filter can veto the rest of
>   the chain if it wants to handle the request itself. A filter can also
>   modify the request and/or the response used in the downstream filters
>   and servlet.

As each of filters can modify/deny the request and moreover they are ordered, the processing of the filter chain must be done **sequentially**.

On the other hand, if you really want to do some async processing, it can be done by forking/joining threads inside a filter.

Comment: Why it is not possible? Assume I have 2 filters: 1st async, 2nd sync. I can run 1st filter and add callback to call 2nd filter after 1st will finish computation. If 2nd filter is async, he will add callback for 3rd, and after all we will just have async request.